# Jasmine testing response failing

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am looking to use Jasmine to test that the requests to the url are sucessful but everytime I try it says that $ is not defined. Any guidance or direction would be helpful thanks.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: "url.com",
    success: showBooks,
});

describe("Spy on ajax call",    function()  {   
    it("should make an  AJAX request with correct setting",             
        function()  {   
            spyOn($, "ajax");       
                expect($.ajax).toHaveBeenCalledWith({   
                type:   "GET",  
                url:    "url.com",  
                dataType:   "json", 
                success:    showBooks
                }); 
        }); 
});
```

EDIT: forgot to add the JQuery library so its now all working.

Comment: $ looks like jQuery, have you loaded it?

Comment: Well looks like I made a stupid mistake not double checking if JQuery was loaded, cheers

Comment: Since you figured it out, do answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 0):

A follow up after the comments with Erasersharp.

```
$ is not defined
```

Looks like you forgot the jQuery, as confirmed by Erasersharp.